# How to start handling the converstation by pressing a button?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a menu of buttons, one of them is Research , when you click on it, it's supposed to ask "What do you want to know about?"  then receive your answer and give you a summary about that from Wikipedia ...

and I want it to be accessible as a command too like give you a summary when you type /Research ...

now my code works perfect using /Research cause this command is the entry_point of my ConverstationHandler

But now I want it to be accessible by pressing the Research button too :

```py
def Click_Button(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    if query.data == "MeMe":
        MeMe(update,context)
    if query.data == "Joke":
        Joke(update,context)
    if query.data == "Research":
        #Here I need to call the following ConverstaionHandler somehow .....

query_handler = CallbackQueryHandler(Click_Button)
dispatcher.add_handler(query_handler)
```

Here is my conversation handler

```py
About = 0
handle_converstation=ConversationHandler(

    '''it calls the ask_wikipedia function using command /Research now I want it to 
     have another entry points too and it's going to be when we press the Research 
     button or in another word when query.data == "Research" '''

    entry_points=[CommandHandler('Research', ask_wikipedia)],
    states={
        About: [MessageHandler(Filters.text, callback=about)]
    },
    fallbacks=[CommandHandler('quit', quit)])

dispatcher.add_handler(handle_converstation)
```

Can anyone tell me How can I start the conversation handler when I press the Research button when query.data == "Research" ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this adding the `CallbackQueryHandler` as an entry point with the attribute `pattern="Research"`

So at the end you should have something like this

```py
entry_points=[CommandHandler('Research', ask_wikipedia),
              CallbackQueryHandler(pattern='Research', callback=func_to_call)],
```

You can see this in the official [docs](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.callbackqueryhandler.html?highlight=CallbackQueryHandler#telegram.ext.CallbackQueryHandler.pattern)
And also used (not in the `entry_points`) on one of [their examples](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/inlinekeyboard2.py#L178)